# Generate dictionaries by permutations/combinations starting from a base dictionary, and associate the result with True/False base on key values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I have a structure similar to dictionaries:

```
c  = {

'usize': { '500': False, '100': True}

'isize':  { '200': False, '800':False, '900':True}

'path':  {'/tmp': False, '/var':True, '/tp12':False;}

}
```

I need to combine all the values, create an array of new dictionary and associate a dictionary with a Bollean values based on keys. Can be use something else than dictionaries.

Example:

```
c1 = {

'usize': 500,
'isize': 200,
'path': '/tmp' }

Associated value, False and False and False = False

c2 = {

'usize': 100,
'isize': 900,
'path': '/var' }

Associated value, True  and True and True = True

c2 = {

'usize': 500,
'isize': 900,
'path': '/var' }

Associated value, False  and True and True = False
```

Comment: Do you have `c1` `c2` and `c3` and you want to have a way to evaluate the associated value for them, or you want to create a list of dictionaries of all elements to associated values?

Comment: also, unless you have a very good reason to be using python 2, strongly consider switching to python 3. Python 2 will be [EOL](https://hg.python.org/peps/rev/76d43e52d978) in 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [itertools product](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and some manipulations of the output to get the desired dicts

```
from itertools import product

c  = {

'usize': { '500': False, '100': True},

'isize':  { '200': False, '800':False, '900':True},

'path':  {'/tmp': False, '/var':True, '/tp12':False}

}

result = []
for group in product(*c.values()): #this makes all product groups of values such as (500, 200, '/var') etc.
    temp = dict(zip(c.keys(), group)) #bring back the keys for every group
    #create a new 'value' key with the boolean result
    temp['value'] = all(c[k][v] for k, v in temp.items()) #change to .iteritems() for python 2
    result.append(temp)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'usize': '500', 'isize': '200', 'path': '/tmp', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '500', 'isize': '200', 'path': '/var', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '500', 'isize': '200', 'path': '/tp12', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '500', 'isize': '800', 'path': '/tmp', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '500', 'isize': '800', 'path': '/var', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '500', 'isize': '800', 'path': '/tp12', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '500', 'isize': '900', 'path': '/tmp', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '500', 'isize': '900', 'path': '/var', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '500', 'isize': '900', 'path': '/tp12', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '100', 'isize': '200', 'path': '/tmp', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '100', 'isize': '200', 'path': '/var', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '100', 'isize': '200', 'path': '/tp12', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '100', 'isize': '800', 'path': '/tmp', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '100', 'isize': '800', 'path': '/var', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '100', 'isize': '800', 'path': '/tp12', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '100', 'isize': '900', 'path': '/tmp', 'value': False},
 {'usize': '100', 'isize': '900', 'path': '/var', 'value': True},
 {'usize': '100', 'isize': '900', 'path': '/tp12', 'value': False}]
```

Comment: I was confused as to if the OP wants to evaluate c1,c2 etc or he wants a list of all evaluations as a lookup table @ParitoshSingh, seems like the latter and my answer misses that completely lol

Comment: eh, it happens. All good. The op says "I need to combine all the values", so i am fairly certain they'd need all possible products.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion I might have is to make a combined dictionary where you chain nested keys together with a delimiter, (I chose `:` any other delimiter can be used as well)

So the original dictionary changes to

```
{'usize:500': False, 'usize:100': True, 
'isize:200': False, 'isize:800': False, 'isize:900': True, 
'path:/tmp': False, 'path:/var': True, 'path:/tp12': False}
```

via the code

```
res = {'{}:{}'.format(key1,key2):value for key1,value1 in c.items() for key2, value in value1.items() }
print(res)
```

We can then easily use the `res` dictionary to compute the boolean values for `c1,c2...` after iterating over with key,value pairs of `c1,c2..` etc

```
c1_val = all(res['{}:{}'.format(k,v)] for k,v in c1.items())
print(c1_val)

c2_val = all(res['{}:{}'.format(k,v)] for k,v in c2.items())
print(c2_val)

c3_val = all(res['{}:{}'.format(k,v)] for k,v in c3.items())
print(c3_val)
```

And the output will be

```
False
True
False
```